# Why does git un-track every file in my repo after a commit?

Tags: git

Occasionally—and I'm not exactly sure when—git will un-track every single file in my project after making a commit. For example:

```bash
% git status
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to upstage)
      new file:   some/new/file

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
      modified:   some/modified/file

% git commit -am "My commit message"
[main abcd1234] My commit message
 10065 files changed, 1644065 deletions(-)
 delete mode 100644 some/file/1
 delete mode 100644 some/file/2
 ...
 [EVERY FILE IN THE REPOSITORY]


% git status
On branch main
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/main' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
      some/file/1
      some/file/2
      ...
      [EVERY FILE/FOLDER IN THE REPOSITORY]

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Git essentially removed every file from the repo, and now they need to be re-added. Nothing in the `git status` suggests that this is about to happen. The issue occurs every couple weeks on this project, seemingly randomly.

Why does this happen and how can I prevent it?

Comment: Broken `.git/index` file?

Comment: "delete mode" on the first commit there? Are you deleting those files yourself?

Comment: Why do you add/stage files when you are going to use `commit -a` anyway? That will commit all modified files, even those that are unstaged.

Comment: "bout to happen. The issue occurs every couple weeks on this project, seemingly randomly. Why does this happen" Because your repo is on a shared drive?

Comment: Potentially relevant: `git commit -a` stages all new changes, including file detentions, prior to commiting. That more-or-less voids the output of the previous `git status`. We don't know what did detected as being changed at the time you ran `git commit`. Is there anything unusual about the filesystem that the repo lives in (e.g., a network filesystem)?

Comment: Does your repository live in a directory that is synced to the Cloud?

Comment: @j6t yes, the repository lives in a folder on my Mac synced to iCloud Drive.

Comment: @matt not a network drive, but a local drive synced to iCloud.

Comment: That would explain it.

Comment: @matt ok so what is the problem exactly? I keep all of my documents in iCloud Drive - why can't I backup git repos too?

Comment: Just move the repo out of there and all will be well. Google "git icloud drive" for more info.